# Merge repeat-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I suggest merging and creating the following tag-synonyms:

- [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating) (252) → [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) (852)
- [repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repetition) (147) → [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) (852)

Comment: It's too bad [repeat] is bigger than [repetition] because the latter sounds more descriptive IMO.

Comment: @iCodez: repeat is simpler, a verb, and also a keyword in many languages, so no wonder it wins over its reified form.

Comment: I wonder, is really useful having *any* of them?

Comment: Speaking as an expert in repeating, I believe so. Speaking as an expert in repeating, I believe so.

Comment: Have *any user* ever achieved a gold-badge (aka super-user status) for any of these tags?

Comment: @cybermonkey No. http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold does not include the repeat tag or one of the other.